# Why is "Taisha" written as "general pardon"?

Tags: yuki-yuna-is-a-hero

In *Yuuki Yuuna wa Yuusha de Aru*, the organization that is responsible for doing things involving the god-tree is called "Taisha". The official (Crunchyroll) subs don't translate this word, but in Japanese, it's written 大赦. As far as I can tell, this is a legal term meaning "general pardon", which is a type of pardon in Japanese law that applies to all people convicted of a particular crime or class of crimes (as contrasted with 特赦 *tokusha* "special pardon", which applies only to specific people). This is a very strange name for an organization.

What is stranger still is that if you know Japanese and you had never seen the term written down, you would probably think that it would be written as the homophone 大社, which means "grand shrine", which makes a lot more sense as the name of an organization.

What is the logic behind writing "Taisha" as "general pardon"?

(I am aware of the "theory" suggesting that you can rearrange the strokes of 友奈 "Yuuna" and get 大赦 "Taisha" [[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/573b6.jpg)]; I do not think that the theory has any merit, since it involves rearranging strokes in a way that does not respect the radicals involved.)

Comment: Hmm... in NoWaYu prequel, “Taisha” is written with the characters 大社.  In WaSuYu and YuYuYu, it is written as 大赦. Maybe it has something to do with the mankai ability? Maybe the Taisha is hiding something  important from them... again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Originally, it was called 大社 (Grand Shrine), but later it's revised to 大赦 (Amnesty).**

In *Nogi Wakaba wa Yuusha de Aru* (Nogi Wakaba is a Hero), the prequel to *Washio Sumi wa Yuusha de Aru* (Washio Sumi is a Hero) and *Yuuki Yuuna wa Yuusha de Aru* (Yuki Yuna is a Hero), the organization was originally named 大社 (Grand Shrine).

From ch. 3, pg. 5,

> **The counter-Vertex organization known as the Taisha (Grand Shrine)** had researched the Shinju's power and discovered a scientific and magic method of utilizing it. The outfit was a result of that research. It was the culmination of the Shinju's blessing and the knowledge of mankind.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

From ch. 19 (final chapter), pg. 23,

> Hinata already seemed to have a plan in mind as she answered Wakaba's question without any hesitation.
>
> - "First, **we will rename the Taisha from 'grand shrine' to 'amnesty' as a self-conscious reminder that we have been granted amnesty and live modestly as human beings**."
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine, couldn't quote more than that to avoid heavy spoiler)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is only speculation, but: In one sense, one could say that the Taisha and Shinju-sama (sorry if that's misspelled, I watched the series dubbed) granted a "general pardon" to humanity by protecting them from the apparently-endless maelstrom of destruction outside the... sorry, I'm blanking on the name for the barrier.